# If I declare 'i' above for loop I am getting the output as 3 3 3 and if I declare 'i' inside for loop I am getting output as 1 2 3

Tags: javascript

Declaring `i` before the *for* loop gives output as *3 3 3*.

```
let i;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  const log = () => {
    console.log(i);
  }
  setTimeout(log, 100);
}
```

//Output 3 3 3

Declaring `i` in the *for* loop gives output as *1 2 3*:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  const log = () => {
    console.log(i);
  }
  setTimeout(log, 100);
}
```

//Output 1 2 3

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: What the reason for this behavior is

Comment: When declared in the head of a `for` loop you get a new `i` variable for every round of the loop.

Comment: Duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `let i = 0;`, the variable `i` has its scope restricted to the block scope of the for loop, e.g. between the two curly braces.

When you have `let i;` outside of the for loop, the variable `i` is restricted to the block scope enclosing the `for` loop, not the scope of the for loop itself, and you see this behavior occur.